# Android SDK Manager is not openning

Tags: android, sdk

> Android SDK Manager does not open.>I have my Android Studio version 2.3 and installed JDK version jdk1.8.0_121.

Comment: 1) What have you tried to do to open it? (pressed which buttons, etc.) 2) Does it show any errors?

Comment: which platform/OS ? how do you open it? what happens when you open it? have you tried to open it as Admin/Root user?